# Css Timeline text alignment

Tags: html, css

folks,

I am trying to build a timeline with css and I have issue with those red circles. I would like to add some information which should be centered text vertically and horizontally inside the red circles (one or 2 words maximum) , may I ask for your help ?

```css
.timeline-image {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 390px;
  height: 390px;
  background: rgba(203, 190, 181, 0.3);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.timeline-image img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
  top: -30px;
}

.timeline ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: #b2b2b2;
}

.timeline ul li:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 87px;
  height: 87px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  top: 76%;
}

.timeline ul li div {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100px;
  top: 120px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: transparent;
}

.timeline ul li:nth-child(even) div {
  left: -439px;
}

.timeline ul li:nth-child(even) div:before {
  right: -15px;
  border-width: 8px 0px 8px 16px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #F45B69;
}

.timeline h3 {
  font-family: "Open-Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 34px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.timeline p {
  font-family: "Open-Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #555;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.timeline ul li a {
  font-family: "Open-Sans-Bold", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.timeline ul li a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<section class="timeline">
  <div class="container">

  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>
        <img src="images/timeline1.jpg" width="324" height="125" title="someText" alt="someText">
        <h3>Lorem</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
        <a href="#" class="read-more">lorem
        <img src="images/example-arrow.png" title="someText" alt="someText">
       </a>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <img src="images/timeline2.jpg" width="324" height="125" title="someText" alt="someText">
        <h3>Lorem</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
        <a href="#" class="read-more">Lorem
        <img src="images/example-arrow.png" title="someText" alt="someText">
       </a>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <img src="images/timeline3.jpg" width="324" height="125" title="someText" alt="someText">
        <h3>Lorem</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
        <a href="#" class="read-more">lorem
        <img src="images/example-arrow.png" title="someText" alt="someText">
       </a>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <img src="images/timeline4.jpg" width="324" height="125" title="someText" alt="someText">
        <h3>Lorem</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
        <a href="#" class="read-more">lorem
        <img src="images/example-arrow.png" title="someText" alt="someText">
       </a>

      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
<!-- timeline -->
```

Comment: Please give more information of what your code is doing.

Comment: nothing for now, I'm just trying to add some centered text inside those red circles but i do not have idea how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pseudo selector :before` then add text using content or you could even add a new `div` and then align that using position `absolute` to center of already styled pseudo selector `:after`

```
.timeline ul li:before {
  content: "Hey";
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 85%;
  left: -18px;
  z-index: 9;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```css
.timeline-image {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 390px;
  height: 390px;
  background: rgba(203, 190, 181, 0.3);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
}

.timeline-image img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
  top: -30px;
}

.timeline ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: #b2b2b2;
  z-index: -1;
}

.timeline ul li:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 87px;
  height: 87px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  z-index: 8;
}

.timeline ul li:before {
  content: "Hey";
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 85%;
  left: -18px;
  z-index: 9;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.timeline ul li div {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100px;
  top: 120px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.timeline ul li:nth-child(even) div {
  left: -439px;
}

.timeline ul li:nth-child(even) div:before {
  right: -15px;
  border-width: 8px 0px 8px 16px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #F45B69;
}

.timeline h3 {
  font-family: "Open-Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 34px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.timeline p {
  font-family: "Open-Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #555;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.timeline ul li a {
  font-family: "Open-Sans-Bold", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.timeline ul li a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<section class="timeline">
  <div class="container">

  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>
        <img src="images/timeline1.jpg" width="324" height="125" title="someText" alt="someText">
        <h3>Lorem</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
        <a href="#" class="read-more">lorem
        <img src="images/example-arrow.png" title="someText" alt="someText">
       </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <img src="images/timeline2.jpg" width="324" height="125" title="someText" alt="someText">
        <h3>Lorem</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
        <a href="#" class="read-more">Lorem
        <img src="images/example-arrow.png" title="someText" alt="someText">
       </a>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <img src="images/timeline3.jpg" width="324" height="125" title="someText" alt="someText">
        <h3>Lorem</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
        <a href="#" class="read-more">lorem
        <img src="images/example-arrow.png" title="someText" alt="someText">
       </a>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <img src="images/timeline4.jpg" width="324" height="125" title="someText" alt="someText">
        <h3>Lorem</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
        <a href="#" class="read-more">lorem
        <img src="images/example-arrow.png" title="someText" alt="someText">
       </a>

      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
<!-- timeline -->
```

Comment: Thank you! If you have time can you explain me with few words how to accomplish the same thing but with division?

Comment: Welcome @PeterSolvien :-), you mean using div, if so then add one new div and then set it's position to absolute, but when styling that you have to use much of negative value. So this pseudo works fine.

Comment: yes, i want to use div because the content of each circle must be different and with pseudo class i am not able to do it. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

CSS

```
.timeline ul li:after{
content:"hello";
text-align:center;
line-height:87px;
}
```

make use of line-height and text-align
hope this helps..

Comment: I am using the same list:after pseudo class to create the red circles so I need another alternative to use for the text, so every of my red circles is genereted by this li:after and I cannot use it. Moreover I cannot use before pseudo class, because the text inside those circles must be different not the same.